# Python pyproject.toml - Installing Submodules from unusually nested directories

Tags: python, virtualenv, setuptools, git-submodules, pyproject.toml

I've a project structure like this.

```
project-dir
├── pyproject.toml
├── bin
│   └── app.py
├── main_pkg
│   └── __init__.py
├── setup.py
└── tools (this is a git submodule)
    ├── setup.py
    ├── a_pkg
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── b_pkg
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── c_pkg
        └── __init__.py
```

My goal is to have `main_pkg` `pkg_a`, `pkg_b`, `pkg_a` all installed in  `.venv/lib/python3.10/site_packages/*` as well as the submodules dependencies with a caveat of not changing the git submodule (write permissions controlled).

The `pyproject.toml` looks like this:

```
[build-system]
build-backend = 'setuptools.build_meta'
requires = ['setuptools >= 63.0.0']

[project]
name = "main_pkg"
version = "3.8.1a"
requires-python = ">3.10.1"

dependencies = [
    "aiohttp >= 3.7.4",
    "aiohttp_cors",
    "aiosql",
    "jsonschema",
    "requests",
    "sentry-sdk"
]

[project.optional-dependencies]
test = [
    "coverage",
    "hypothesis",
    "pytest"
]
dev = [
    "psycopg2-binary >= 2.9.5",
    "sqlalchemy >= 1.4.43",
    "black",
    "flake8",
    "Flake8-pyproject",
    "isort",
    "pre-commit",
    "python-dotenv",
    "vermin",
]

[project.scripts]
main = "bin.app:start"

[tool.setuptools]
include-package-data = true
package-dir = {main_pkg="main_pkg", a_pkg="tools/a_pkg", b_pkg="tools/b_pkg", c_pkg="tools/b_pkg"}

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = [".", "tools"]
include = ["main", "a_pkg", "b_pkg", "c_pkg"]
```

Problem is that when I run the install, `tools` is installed like this with a build folder being inside the package.

```
.venv/lib/python3.10/site_packages/
├── main_pkg
│   └── __init__.py
├── tools
    ├── setup.py
    ├── build
    │   └── lib/* 
    ├── a_pkg
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── b_pkg
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── c_pkg
        └── __init__.py
```

Where as I would like it installed as like this:

```
.venv/lib/python3.10/site_packages/
├── main_pkg
│   └── __init__.py
├── a_pkg
│   └── __init__.py
├── b_pkg
│   └── __init__.py
└── c_pkg
    └── __init__.py
```

In the pyproject.toml above, I've tried package discovery under   `[tool.setuptools.packages.find]` but it messes up the installs and build/ directory goes on holidays to the site-packages.

Attempted to explicitly state the packages in `[tool.setuptools].package-dir` however this just doesn't install them at all now not even the `tools` dependencies.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?